# How can I set the MAILTO variable for an at job on AIX?

Tags: cron, aix, at

I'm calling at jobs on AIX servers using this method:

`/usr/bin/at now +1 minute << EOF
chmod 700 /var/tmp/somescript.sh
cd /var/tmp
sh /var/tmp/somescript.sh > 2>&1
EOF`

If ever some output is generated (because i.e. the script I'm calling doesn't exist), an email is sent to the default mail configured for cron jobs. I know this is default behavior and that is fine. However, if I want to change the MAILTO variable used, how can I do it using the method above ?

I tried adding MAILTO=myaddress@mydomain.com in the at script but that didn't work. The mail still went to the default address.

i.e.

`/usr/bin/at now +1 minute << EOF
MAILTO=myaddress@mydomain.com
chmod 700 /var/tmp/somescript.sh
cd /var/tmp
sh /var/tmp/somescript.sh > 2>&1
EOF`

The reason I'm using this method is because the jobs are created on a fly by another system, but this is irrelevant. I need to do it this way and can't edit the crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was an alias defined for root in /etc/mail/aliases and this is where it was coming from. There's no way for me to bypass it per-command with this on, as any mail sent to root's mailbox will automatically get forwarded to that alias.

Comment: if you have any control over the script, pipe its output to a logfile or to its own mail command

Comment: The issue was not to be able to send the output by mail, but rather that it wasn't being sent to root at all.

Comment: if you [capture all of the output](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/at.htm) then `at` won't have anything to mail (or you can send that redirected output in an email to someone else)

Comment: I also know that, but that was not the question. It works with a proper redirect, but if for whatever reason output is generated by mistake root will get it. It was a general question.